# R8 error with 'com.google.android.play.core.assestpacks.' on androidTest builds

Tags: android, android-testing, android-r8

When building the androidTest apk I get the multiple of the follow error:

```
'com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.c' cannot be mapped to 'Lcom/google/android/play/core/assetpacks/c;' because it is in conflict with an existing class with the same name. This usually happens when compiling a test application against a source application and having short generic names in the test application. Try giving 'Lcom/google/android/play/core/assetpacks/c;' a more specific name or add a keep rule to keep 'com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.c'.
```

However my other builds work fine.  Disabling minify works of course, but I want to test against a minify build.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and "android.enableR8=false" helps me because I use proguard at the moment.

gradle.properties file,
android.enableR8=false